# Exclude specific file to be uploaded from upload files tree with azcopy

Tags: azure, file-upload, azcopy

Trying to copy from a onprem network share (that I can only read) to Azure storage share.

I've done this succefully but there is a specific large file that I don't want to copy (upload) in the root.

Is there a pattern that I can use? Something opposite to:

```
&$azCopyPath /L /Y /S /source:"$sharePath" /dest:"$destShareUri"  /DestSAS:"$destShareSAS"  /pattern:FileToExclude.Zip
```

Seems strange that there's no exclude pattern or option, since I would expect that this could be very useful in some scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, there is no exclude option and I agree, it would be useful in some situations.

As a workaround you could use PowerShell to retrieve all items of a specific folder and exclude it using the `Where-Object` cmdlet with the `-ne`(not equal) operator. Then you can iterate over each file (you want to upload) and call az copy for that. Example:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object Name -ne 'Analyze.ps1' | ForEach-Object {
    &$azCopyPath /L /Y /S /source:"$sharePath" /dest:"$destShareUri" /DestSAS:"$destShareSAS" /pattern:$($_.Name)
}
```